# Use of Out-null in Get-WMIobject

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Hello can somebody help me to hide the output of a Get-WMIobject query.. Tried out-null but the parameters i am not able to use later

```
$CurrentPageFileC = (Get-WmiObject -computername $server -Namespace root\CIMV2 -Query "select * from Win32_PageFileSetting where name='c:\\pagefile.sys'") | out-null
$CurrentPageFileC.InitialSize = 4096
$CurrentPageFileC.MaximumSize = 4096
$CurrentPageFileC.put()
```

Comment: Sorry i was mistaken, inserted the out-null in a wrong place.. :)

Comment: Why did it not hide? Or you are receiving an error? This should suffice: `$CurrentPageFileC = Get-WmiObject -computername $server -Namespace root\CIMV2 -Query "select * from Win32_PageFileSetting where name='c:\\pagefile.sys'"`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i was mistaken, inserted the out-null in a wrong place.. :)

```
$CurrentPageFileC = (Get-WmiObject -computername $server -Namespace root\CIMV2 -Query "select * from Win32_PageFileSetting where name='c:\\pagefile.sys'") 
$CurrentPageFileC.InitialSize = 4096
$CurrentPageFileC.MaximumSize = 4096
$CurrentPageFileC.put() |out-null
```